# Python NamedTuple type hierarchy

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I'm generating sequences of simple commands in Python, and the commands have various numbers of bool, float and int fields with various names.

I'm representing them as NamedTuple classes, eg the move command is

```
class G1(NamedTuple):
    """
    Move command with speed in mm/s
    """
    x: float = None
    y: float = None
    z: float = None
    speed: float = None
    absolute: bool = True
```

They're all specific examples of Gcodes, which is the name of the command language, so I'd like to have a type called Gcode where `issubclass(G1, Gcode) == True`. Then I could type-hint various functions as `List[Gcode]` and describe some methods which should be common to all Gcodes.

I tried just defining

```
class Gcode(NamedTuple):
    pass
class G1(Gcode):
    x: float = None
    ...
```

However G1's constructors no longer work as expected.

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I wasn't having any luck on search because there are a lot of questions about subclassing NamedTuples to add fields to them, which is not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: "G1's constructors no longer work as expected" in what sense? What's the issue?